# How to drop duplicates in pandas but keep more than the first

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2]})
>> df
   a
0  1
1  2
2  2
3  2
4  2
5  1
6  1
7  1
8  2
9  2
```

I want to drop duplicates if they exceed a certain threshold `n` and replace them with that minimum. Let's say that `n=3`. Then, my target dataframe is

```
>> df
   a
0  1
1  2
2  2
3  2
5  1
6  1
7  1
8  2
9  2
```

EDIT: Each set of consecutive repetitions is considered separately. In this example, rows 8 and 9 should be kept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create unique value for each consecutive group, then use `groupby` and `head`:

```
group_value = np.cumsum(df.a.shift() != df.a)
df.groupby(group_value).head(3)

# result:

   a
0  1
1  2
2  2
3  2
5  1
6  1
7  1
8  3
9  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
N = 3
df[df.groupby('a').cumcount().lt(N)]
```

Output:

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  2
3  2
5  1
6  1
8  3
9  3
```

For the last N:

```
df[df.groupby('a').cumcount(ascending=False).lt(N)]
```

##### apply on consecutive repetitions

```
df[df.groupby(df['a'].ne(df['a'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount().lt(3)])
```

Output:

```
   a
0  1
1  2
2  2
3  2
5  1
6  1
7  1  # this is #3 of the local group
8  3
9  3
```

#### advantages of boolean indexing

You can use it for many other operations, such as setting values or masking:

```
group = df['a'].ne(df['a'].shift()).cumsum()
m = df.groupby(group).cumcount().lt(N)

df.where(m)
     a
0  1.0
1  2.0
2  2.0
3  2.0
4  NaN
5  1.0
6  1.0
7  1.0
8  3.0
9  3.0
```

```
df.loc[~m] = -1

   a
0  1
1  2
2  2
3  2
4 -1
5  1
6  1
7  1
8  3
9  3
```

Comment: This won't work when you have a repetition, say: `[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,3,3]`. The second set of `1`s will be also be deleted, even if it should be considered another group.

Comment: @irene easy to handle, let me update

Answer (score 0):

```
df.assign(col1=df.diff().ne(0).cumsum())\
    .groupby('col1').a.head(3)

Output:

   a
0  1
1  2
2  2
3  2
5  1
6  1
8  3
9  3
```